# JAside Panels push back from other view

Tags: ios7

I use JAside Panels for my app. I set up leftView, centerView and rightView. In left view I have a tableView, in table I have a menu. Now I want to selected a cell to push other view like navigation (have back button in left). How to do it with JAside Panels? Help me please,

==> pass 2 hours, No One help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assign the nib names of each view controller for each menu from the left panel and then present it to the center panel.